Unable to set new configuration for AWSServiceManager on session token expiration - iOS
Hi I am also facing the same issue
My Code Snippet
func isKeysSetToAWSS3Enviroment(path: String) {
if let keys = AWSCredentials.getKeysDetails() {

    let accessKey = keys.accessKey ?? ""
    let secretKey = keys.secretKey ?? ""
    let sessionKey = keys.sessionId ?? ""

    let credentialsProvider = AWSBasicSessionCredentialsProvider(accessKey: accessKey, secretKey: secretKey, sessionToken: sessionKey)
    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
    if let crdeentials = AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration {
        print("AWSCredentials Before \(crdeentials.credentialsProvider.credentials())")
    }
    AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
    print("AWSCredentials After \(AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration.credentialsProvider.credentials())")

}

}
Printing the credentials before and after are always same it not getting changed.
I am completely blocked:
Our SDK Version pod 'AWSS3','2.10.3'
